# How does Hunter's Bane work?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, stealth

i am a new Pathfinder2E DM, and during my third session or so, the players received a Talisman called [Hunter's Bane](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=217), copying from the AON:

> Source Core Rulebook pg. 567 2.0
>
> Activate: Free Action (envision); Trigger: An undetected enemy hits you
> with an attack; Requirements: You are trained in Survival.
>
> This talisman is a ring of dried, interwoven leaves. When you activate the hunter’s
> bane, you sense the exact location of the attacker, making it hidden
> from you instead of undetected. If the attacker is behind lead, the
> hunter’s bane fails and is wasted.

I'm a bit stuck on how its supposed to work exactly, since from my understanding, once a creature that is undetected or hidden attacks, it becomes observed after the attack, as is written in the page for the [Hide](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=62) and [Sneak](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=63) on successes.

> You cease being hidden if you do anything except Hide, Sneak, or Step.
> **If you attempt to Strike a creature, the creature remains flat-footed
> against that attack, and you then become observed.** If you do anything
> else, you become observed just before you act unless the GM determines
> otherwise. The GM might allow you to perform a particularly
> unobtrusive action without being noticed, possibly requiring another
> Stealth check.

If an opponent attacked, regardless if it hit you or not, it should now be detected, and since the trigger says when it **hits** you, i don't think it can be used if the enemy attacks you and hides and sneaks again in the same turn. If an enemy Strikes you, it should not be undetected or hiden anymore, so even if you could active it's effect, it is already observed, so the effect is wasted.

It doesn't seen to have a duration so i don't think you can use it to keep tracking the enemy's direction after the attack.

Is my comprehension of stealth wrong, or is this talisman supposed to work in more niche scenarios that i'm not fully aware of yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hunter's Bane talisman is useful against creatures that don't rely on the Stealth skill to remain undetected.

For example, if you're in complete darkness, or blinded by any reason, or the creature is [invisible](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=426), etc.

In those scenarios, even after attacking the creature would remain undetected, unless you have a [sense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=410) other than vision capable of detecting the creature.